How to get system plugins to load without specifying them in the world SDF file
Is it possible to specify server plugins other than the sdf world file?
I would like to provide a world in which the user is able to spawn and control their own robot after the server has started. Because the robot model provided by the user, it could depend on any system plugin (either custom or provided by Gazebo), and the world wouldn't know what are the dependencies beforehand.
Is it possible to specify a server plugin to be loaded other than directly in the world file?
I'm looking for ways to do this either after the server is already running / the world is loaded, or as command line arguments for the server when the server is created.
